# Swift 3 how to anchor bottom when width is exceeded

Tags: uiview, swift3, autolayout, anchorpoint

I am coding an app and I want to know how I can anchor a view to the bottom instead of right side of the previous view when total width in the same row exceeds device width.

Basically like this:

```
View 1: width=150 anchor to superview's leftAnchor
View 2: width=500 anchor to view1's rightAnchor
View 3: width=1000 anchor to view1's bottomAnchor because total width in same row
exceeds device width

#device width=1200
```

Any help is appreciated. Sorry for bad English, not a native speaker.

Ps. all heights are same, width is dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main challenge was I couldn't know the width of my views until they are constrained.

So I used swift's estimation.

```
let size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50)
let attributeHeight = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)]
let estimatedHeight = NSString(string: _title).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributeHeight, context: nil)
self._estimatedWidth = estimatedHeight.width + 32
```

after that it was easy to anchor them according to my needs with a for loop